# MongoDB and Twitter query

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, tweepy

I've collected tweet via the Streaming API and would like to make queries from the mongodb.

I'm new to MongoDB, so would this be the correct syntax to query for tweets with either coordinates or location information:

```
cursor = coll.find({"coordinates.type" : "Point"},{"coordinates" :1} or {"location": not "null" }, tailable = True, timeout = False)
```

I'm using pymongo and this is a capped collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at both the **$or** and **$ne** operators.

From the official MongoDB docs:

**$or**: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/

> The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or
>   more  and selects the documents that satisfy at least one
>   of the .

**$ne**: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/

> $ne selects the documents where the value of the field is not equal
>   (i.e. !=) to the specified value. This includes documents that do not
>   contain the field.

You need to rewrite your query as following:

```
cursor = coll.find({ $or : [{"coordinates.type" : "Point"},{"location": {$ne :"null" }}]},{"coordinates" :1}, tailable = True, timeout = False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be:                                    cursor = coll.find({ $or : [{"coordinates.type" : "Point"},{"coordinates": 1}]},{"location" : {$ne: "null"}}, tailable = True, timeout = False)

Comment: The first argument to the find() function is the condition, and the second one refers to the subset of fields you want to retrieve (in your case, "coordinates").

Comment: Ok, so coordinates.type and location are conditions and coordinates will then be a subset of coordinates.type